# Why can't we directly print the output of a lambda function/expression directly as a string,list, or tuple?

Tags: python, list, function, lambda, list-comprehension

I am using Python 3. I am trying to write a `lambda function/expression` and generate a string type output. I am not sure what I am not understanding in this issue.

```
Cel = [39.5, 36.5, 37.3, 37.8]
Fer = lambda x: (float(9)/5*x for x in Cel + 32)
print(Fer)
```

prints:

```
<function <lambda> at 0x7fafc369eea0>
```

But, I want the list of values as:

```
[103.1, 97.70, 99.14, 100.03]
```

I then tried map with lambda

```
Fer2 = map(lambda x: (float(9)/5)*x + 32, Cel)
print(Fer2) # prints:
<map object at 0x7fafc36b5b38> # still no success

for x in Fer:
    print(x)  # this doesn't work and gives following error
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

for x in Fer2:
    print(x) # but this works and prints
             103.10
             97.7
             99.14
             100.039
```

Why can't I get `print(Fer or Fer2)` simply as a a list of values, like:
[103.1, 97.70, 99.14, 100.03]

How do I solve this within lambda, without writing another `def function`?

Comment: Does it need to be a lambda, why not a list comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `lambda`, if you used a function you would run into the same problem - `map` returns an object, which is an 
*iterable*, ie. it can be converted to a list of values, but it **is not** a list of values. To print such a list, you must explicitly require its creation:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: (float(9)/5)*x + 32, Cel)))
```

Answer (score 6):

not quite sure why you need the lambda at all this is a simple list comprehensions

```
Fer = [32+float(9)/5*x for x in Cel]
```

or if you want to use lambda, you will have to use map

```
Fer = list(map(lambda x: (float(9)/5*x + 32),Cel))
```

Since you are iterating through Fer you can leave out the `list`

```
Fer = map(lambda x: (float(9)/5*x + 32),Cel)
```

Your current attempt is basically trying to mix map and list comprehensions. To elaborate further, what you are doing with the next line of code is to create a lambda function and assign it to a variable called `Fer` which is not what you want.

```
Fer = lambda x: (float(9)/5*x for x in Cel + 32)
```

Comment: I didn't say you did, but, other people did. Not, blaming on you.

Comment: Oky doky. As someone who often downvotes questions. I didn't really see much wrong with yours. However some people may have been annoyed by the bold texts

Comment: Anyway, you have my +1 :-)

Comment: I put the part on bold which is intent to be the main question of the overall problem - so people can see it better and don't have to search what the question is asking. Sometime, people don't think twice and just downvote the question for no reason - Do they really use their brain to think or something else... I have some very good question on SE, but they don't really get attention, and someone puts a freaking old repeat question, and people are just squirming to write answers just to get upjump - Those questions already have answers. Sorry, just became a little off the mood. Thanks much !

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer to use map with a defined function as opposed to lambda

```
def func(e):
    return float(((9/5)*e)+32)
```

Also if you want to create a list or tuple with map() in Python 3 you have to put list( or tuple( before map()

```
Cel = [39.5, 36.5, 37.3, 37.8]
Fer = list(map(func,Cel))
print (Fer)
```

Also it seems like list comprehension is faster in this case (probably because Cel is short, over long lists and many function calls map would be slightly faster I think):

```
import time
Cel = [39.5, 36.5, 37.3, 37.8]

def func(e):
    return float(((9/5)*e)+32)

st = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    Fer = [32+float(9)/5*x for x in Cel]
end = time.time()
print ('COMP TIME: '+str(end-st))

st = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    Fer = list(map(func,Cel))
end = time.time()
print ('MAP TIME: '+str(end-st))
```

Results:

```
COMP TIME: 1.8918001651763916
MAP TIME: 2.031294584274292
```

Answer (score 0):

**So here we are :P**
*and this even works :)*

```
print((lambda x, y: (x + y,x * y))(5, 3))
```

Comment: Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.